# Amazon Web Service - Lambda

Tags: lambda

Собираюсь осваивать Amazon Web Service - Lambda.
Но перед началом хотелось бы узнать:

1. Можно ли загружать в Lambda уже готовое стороннее приложение/программу, или работает только с написанным кодом?
2. (следует из первого) можно ли обеспечить доступ к интернету приложения, работающего из оболочки AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 0):

1. На сколько помню, у лямды есть даже свой редактор кода, что не составить труда написать свое приложение, например на питоне. Так же были способы загрузить полностью весь проект.
2. Лямба - это функции или набор функций (приложение) которое уже имеет доступ к интернету, а по AMI Roles еще и к твоим ресурсам Амазона. Главное писать свое приложение используя SDK Амазона, на питоне оно точно есть.